# Difference between two different objects in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, blend4web

first of all thanks a lot to help me out with this little problem.

I am trying to load a 3D map in ThreeJS and everything works fine except 2 objects. Here is the problem: When I add material to my objects, they all work as expected, but two of them they just disappear when I apply material.

[image]

As you can see in the image, there two different kind of objects, one is the "soccer court limits", they are an object without material where you can perfectly see the shape. But as you can also see in the picture, there is another kind of object which are the trees. As you can see they both should be the same kind of object, but one has a perfect shape and the other has many many many lines. The one with all the lines are the objects that disappear when I apply the material.

Any idea why? What's the difference between both objects? In Blender I see them with the same proprieties, I don't know if I am doing something wrong when I export the 3D map into an .obj file.

Thanks,

Oriol López

Comment: Looks like inverted normals problem. Try to recalculate normals and apply scale to be sure that models haven't negative scale

Comment: @Crantisz I just tried and it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: It is hard to guess from just a screenshot, but if those are lines then you may need to use [LineMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=line#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial) instead of the mesh materials? It is not possible to turn lines into a mesh just by changing the material, if the geometry does not contain proper triangles.

Can you share the `.blend`? Something there may explain why those export as lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertices were not right connected.